# Create JSON string with key and value form in C++

Tags: c++, json, string

We can create JSON file using PHP or JavaScript. Can we encode string format into JSON-encoded string using function or API?

Any useful information will be helpful.

Comment: This is the library I use: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: Not in the standard library. There are tons of libraries that can do that for you though.

Comment: For faster JSON library, you may google rapidjson

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is nothing in the Standard-Library, but you can find a List of Libraries on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs).
Just go to the sections for JSON and Serialization.